# Regex between white space and =

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a Regex that will select everything between a whitespace and =.

From the following lines

> Window x:Class="QuiddlerGUI.MainWindow"
>   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

I would like it to select `x:Class` and `xmlns`. The closest I could get was this but it was not stopping at white space.

```
(?<=)(.*?)(?==)
```

I am using the regex to try and select text in a RichTextBox to attempt and change the color of the text.

```
foreach(TextColors color in textColors)
    {
        var start = body.Document.ContentStart;

        while (start != null && start.CompareTo(body.Document.ContentEnd) < 0)
        {
            if (start.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
            {
                var match = color.RegularExpression.Match(start.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward));

                var textrange = new TextRange(start.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index, LogicalDirection.Forward), start.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index + match.Length, LogicalDirection.Backward));

                textrange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, color.TextColor);
                    start = textrange.End;

                }
                start = start.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            }
        }
```

Comment: [You can't parse XML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

Comment: Just `\S+(?==)` should be enough (unless the values can have a `=` sign - then you should think of a proper way of parsing the strings).

Comment: In C#, there are a lot of XML parsing tools at hand. Regex is a means of last resort only.

Comment: It is being put into a rich text field not really needing to parse just trying to color the text

Comment: Do you realize you can just split the string and get these substrings without regex? [**See this demo**](http://ideone.com/5cA5Z3). I will post if you consider a non-regex approach.

Comment: If I were to split the string then how would I change the color of the text within the richtextbox?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `(?<=\s)[^=]*`

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\s)` will look behind for a whitespace.
- `[^=]*` will match everything until a `=` is met.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cH6mE5/1)**

Comment: I tried this RegularExpression = new Regex("(?<=\s)[^=]*", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), and it gives an error of unrecognized escape character

Comment: @jsomers89: Incase you are using Java use `\\s` instead of `\s`.

Comment: It is C#. Verbatim string literals should be used: `@"REGEX_HERE"`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
" (.*?)="
```

It search for a space, followed by any character until it founds an equal sign, looking for the shortest string (regexp are greedy).